# Run your own podcast on asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, podcast

Hope this is the right stackexchange for this question... also I tried to tag this with "podcasting" but of course I can't do that yet...

I'm looking for a simple asp.net script for running a self-hosted podcast. I can develop my own but before I invest the time I'd prefer to work from an existing code-base. prefer something with stats and analytics, as well as simple sharing to social networks and the like.

it needs to be self-hosted, so please don't suggest websites that I have to sign up for; we want to run this entirely on our local servers.

thanks!

Comment: Added podcast tag for you

Answer (score 2):

http://www.xigla.com/apodcast/features.htm

Check it out.
its a very easy script to write, and would be very easy to do if you were doing it with IIS7 bitrate throttling or streaming..